# error en SQL server en consulta a un servidor vinculado

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Buenas tardes,
Tengo vinculado sqlServer con PostgreSQL, la conexión es exitosa, puedo ver las bases de datos que tengo en PostgreSQL a excepción de las tablas de las bases de datos, caso contrario es cuando quiero acceder a las tablas de la base de datos que viene por defecto "postgres".
Adjunto imagen del error cuando intento ver las tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas un Select a una tabla de un servidor vinculado la sintaxis es.

```
Select * from [ServidorVinculado]...[NombreTabla]
```

Comment: Hola J Luis, gracias por tu respuesta, tengo conocimiento de lo que me indicas, utilizando openquery. Necesito ver las tablas y no puedo, sabes como puedo solucionar ese error?

Comment: Valida si el proveedor OLE DB permite visualizar, pudiera ser una versión tipo Trial que esta limitado.

Comment: " Intellisoft OLEDB Provider for Postgres Trial " , asi es el nombre del proveedor OLE DB instalado